# Не работает код объекта

Tags: javascript, html, объекты

После нажатия кнопки вся страница просто заменяется на белую

```js
function print (text) {
    document.write();
}

var Name, Age;
var y = new Date;

function userValue (name, age, dateOfBirth) {
    this.name =  name;
    this.age =  age;
    this.dateOfBirth = y.getFullYear() - age;
}

function conf() { 
    document.getElementById ('inp1').value = Name;
    document.getElementById ('inp2').value = Age;

    var user1 = new userValue (Name, Age);

    print ('Your name is ' + user1.Name);
    print ('Your age is ' + user1.Age);
    print ('You were born in' + user1.dateOfBirth);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Input your name" id="inp1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Input your age" id="inp2">
    <button onclick="conf(this)">Ok</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: В объявлении самой функции нет парамерта, хотя при нажатии его передаёте? `function conf()`

Comment: @Pashok для того, чтобы определить, к какому объекту относится действие функции, насколько я понимаю. Но без этого код вообще никак не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всем потому что в функции `print`  находится метод `document.write()`, который ничего не принимает. Исправьте на `document.write(text)` и все будет гуд. На странице все появится, но переменные которые вы передаете будут `undefined` и NaN

Дополняю: так как js чувствителен к регистру, данные которые вы передаете в функцию `print` идут как `undefined`. Достаточно посмотреть что находится в объекте user1, в нем все свойства с маленькой буквы, а значит вот так будет правильно:

```
print ('Your name is ' + user1.name);
print ('Your age is ' + user1.age);
print ('You were born in' + user1.dateOfBirth);
```

Comment: А с чем это связано?

Comment: @НикитаПопов Что именно?

Comment: Почему выдаетundefined и NaN? И как это можно исправить?

Comment: Выдает undefined, потому что такое свойство не найдено. А NaN это типа неверный формат, или чет такое)